# Do stat boosts ("buffs") survive faints or switches in Pokemon Go Battle League?

Tags: pokemon-go

Fighting in Go Battle League, if my Pokemon gets a stat boost (e.g., increased/decreased attack/defense), and the opponent subsequently faints or switches, does my Pokemon still have the buff?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Attack and Defense stats changes are **now cleared after swapping** during combat.

As confirmed in official [v0.165.0 patch notes](https://pokemonblog.com/2020/01/24/new-pokemon-go-update-version-0-131-0-and-0-165-0-now-live-on-ios-and-android-full-patch-notes-revealed/).

Buffs are reset only on the switched Pokemon. If your own Pokemon stays on the field its buffs are retained.
Nothing will ever reset your own buffs if the opponent's Pokemon is switched or faints.

Comment: So if *my* Pokemon gets an attack increase or defense decrease, and the opponent switches/faints, then my Pokemon continues with those buffs?

Comment: Yes, while your Pokemon stays in battle buffs/debuffs are retained, no matter what happens with your opponent's Pokemon.

Comment: If you want to quote something more official than Reddit, the patch notes for [v0.165.0](https://pokemonblog.com/2020/01/24/new-pokemon-go-update-version-0-131-0-and-0-165-0-now-live-on-ios-and-android-full-patch-notes-revealed/) state "*Attack and Defense stats changes are now cleared after swapping during combat*" (the linked source isn't Niantic, as their official patch notes for this version has been archived)

Comment: @Wondercricket I took the first source available, as I remembered this from personal experience. But thanks, answer edited

Comment: Official Niantic blog notes are still available, including the [2019/12 Community Note](https://pokemongolive.com/en/post/combatrebalance-dec2019/) announcing the combat changes.